# how to merge multiple scripts and use functions to show output

Tags: powershell

A couple of you (Shay especially!) helped me yesterday and I have managed to come up with multiple scripts and am now merging them into one.

The problem is that I have put them all into "Functions" and one function relies on the successful check on a hotfix - if the hotfix is not installed then the script has to stop right there and then - that is the first check the script does. How do I get the next function to call the successful output of the hotfix function?

Also I have no idea how to call the functions - ie at the bottom I put the name of the functions one line after each other but ended up looping over and over!

hope someone can assist.

```
Write-Host "=================================="
Write-Host "Pre-Staging Script for DFSR Server"
Write-Host "=================================="

Function Service
{
    Write-Host "=================================="
    Write-Host "Checking Service Installation"
    Write-Host "=================================="

    write-host "This will check if Hotfix KB979808 is installed." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Cyan
    write-host "This is required for Windows Server 2008 R2 Robocopying"  -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host ""

    $hotfix1 = Get-HotFix -id KB979808 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

        If($hotfix1)
        {
            Write-Host "Hotfix is installed you may proceed" -foregroundcolor "green"
            Write-Host ""
        }
    else
        {
        Write-Host "Hotfix is NOT installed - Please ensure you install this hotfix BEFORE" -ForegroundColor "red"
        Write-host "Copying any data" -foregroundcolor "red"
        Write-Host ""
        }
}

Function Robocopy ($hotfix1)
 {
    Write-Host "============="
    Write-Host "Robocopy Data" 
    Write-Host "============="

    $Source = Read-Host "Please enter path of SOURCE"
    $Destination = Read-Host "Please enter path of TARGET"

    $Output = Read-Host "Please enter where to place output file eg c:\temp\COPY.log"

    robocopy $Source $Target /b /e /copyall /r:1 /xd dfsrprivate /log:$Output /tee
 }

Function Comparision
{
    Write-Host "==============================================="
    Write-Host "Checking Directory Count and Folder comparision" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -BackgroundColor Cyan -ForegroundColor Black
    Write-Host "==============================================="
    Write-Host ""

    $Source = Read-Host "Please enter Source directory to check"
    $Target = Read-Host "Please enter Target directory to check"
    Write-Host ""
    If($source -and (Test-Path -Path $source -PathType Container))
    {
        "There are $(@(Get-ChildItem $Source).Count) items in the '$Source' directory"  
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "Please enter a directory"
        }
        If($source -and (Test-Path -Path $Target -PathType Container))
        {
            "There are $(@(Get-ChildItem $Target).Count) items in the '$Target' directory"  
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host "Please enter a directory"
    }

    Write-Host ""
    $child1 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -Force
    $child2 = Get-ChildItem -Path $Target -Recurse -Force

    Compare-Object $child1 -DifferenceObject $child2 -Property Name

    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "NOTE:" -BackgroundColor Cyan -ForegroundColor Black
    Write-Host "Any symbols with '=>' mean that the file Does NOT exist in SOURCE but is in the Target" -BackgroundColor Cyan -ForegroundColor Black
    Write-Host "Any symbols with '<=' mean that the file Does NOT exist in TARGET but is in the Source" -BackgroundColor Cyan -ForegroundColor Black
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the hotfix found in the function `Service`, you should return the hotfix to a variable. The function would look like this:

```
Function Service
{
    Write-Host "=================================="
    Write-Host "Checking Service Installation"
    Write-Host "=================================="

    write-host "This will check if Hotfix KB979808 is installed." -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Cyan
    write-host "This is required for Windows Server 2008 R2 Robocopying"  -ForegroundColor Black -BackgroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host ""

    # This will return any output.
    Get-HotFix -id KB979808 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

}
```

Then the function calls would be:

```
$hotfix = Service
if($hotfix) {
    Robocopy
}
else {
    # This will exit the script.
    return
}
```

Function `Robocopy` doesn't need `$hotfix1` as a parameter since it's not used anywhere in the function.

The `Robocopy` function is probably looping because the call to robocopy.exe is the same as your `Robocopy` function; try adding ".exe" to the robocopy.exe call. It is important to name functions to accurately reflect their purpose. `Service` could be `Get-HotFixKB979808` and `Robocopy` could be `Start-MyRobocopy`

Having said all that, since your functions do very specific things, they really don't need to be their own functions. You could change them to be more reusable by having them accept parameters.

Comment: absolutly fantastic! thanks a lot for that - I have changed the script and ran it and all worked fine. One question - how do I change the script to accept parameters?.....might have a read on that..

Comment: You could accept parameters like, `function MyRobocopy ($Sorce,$Target) { robocopy $Source $Target /b /e /copyall /r:1 /xd dfsrprivate /log:$Output /tee`. You would call it like `MyRobocopy C:\Temp\MyFolder D:\Temp\MyFolder`. Look at `help about_functions` for more on functions.